# Python & Django - 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GoalCategoryTest'' when trying to import TestCase

Tags: python, django

So I have this `TestCase` file

`CategorySearchTest.py`

```
class CategorySearchTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    # Generates Test DB data to persist throughout all tests
    def setUpTestData(cls) -> None:
        cls.access_token = get_test_user_access_token()
        cls.user = get_or_create_test_user_in_DB()
        cls.goal_category_name_list = ['Health', 'Fitness', 'Art', 'Relationships', 'Artist']
```

I'm trying to import this in the **init**.py file in the same folder so I can run all the tests in this folder with the command `python manage.py test cheers\test\CategoriesTest`.

my `__init__.py` file looks like this

```
from GoalCategoryTest import *
```

then here's my folder structure

[image]

I'm getting the error from my `__init__.py` file which is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GoalCategoryTest'`. Why is this happening?

I've tried

```
from GoalCategoryTest import *
```

and

```
import GoalCategoryTest
```

also tried

```
from CategoriesTests.GoalCategoryTest import *
```

and all give the same error.

I also tried

```
from .GoalCategoryTest import *
```

which throws the exception `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cheers.test.CategoriesTest'`, which I think pertains to the `__init__.py` file under `cheers/test`

`cheers/test/__init__.py`

```
from cheers.test.CategoriesTests import *
from cheers.test.CreatePostTests.DeclareGoalPostTest import *
from cheers.test.CreatePostTests.JourneyTest import *
from cheers.test.CreatePostTests.PhotoTest import *
from cheers.test.CreatePostTests.UpdateGoalPostMediaTest import *
from cheers.test.CreatePostTests.UpdateGoalPostTest import *
from cheers.test.ExploreTests.ExploreFeedTest import *
from cheers.test.GoalTests.GoalTest import *
from cheers.test.HomeTests.HomeTest import *
from cheers.test.JoinGoalTests.FollowJoinGoalTest import *
from cheers.test.JoinGoalTests.JoinGoalTest import *
from cheers.test.ModifyPostTests.ModifyPostTest import *
from cheers.test.ReplyTests.CreateReplyTest import *
from cheers.test.ReplyTests.DeleteReplyTest import *
from cheers.test.ReplyTests.GetReplyTest import *
from cheers.test.SwaggerTests.SwaggerTest import *
from cheers.test.UserTests.FollowUserTest import *
from cheers.test.UserTests.GetUserInfoTest import *
from cheers.test.UserTests.UserSearchTest import *
```

Comment: you should use this `from CategoriesTests.GoalCategoryTest import *`

Comment: @Midoki but the `__init__.py` file is inside the `CategoriesTests` folder. My PyCharm linter isn't showing it as a possible reference.

Comment: @Midoki I tried it and got the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CategoriesTests'
`

Comment: Side note: if you named the test files `test*.py` (i.e. for example `test_goals.py`), django would find all the test cases itself. You could then run all tests of the `CategorieTests` package by using `python manage.py test cheers.test.CategoriesTest` - without having to import all the files in the package's `__init__`.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/

Comment: Not a side note: try `from cheers.test.CategoriesTest.GoalCategoryTest import *`. Python won't find GoalCategoryTest with `from GoalCategoryTest import *`, unless the module is in its immediate search path. Pycharm seems to be too smart for its own good by not flagging this as problematic. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to have different sub-folders in your `test` folder that can be run you need to name all your test files as `test*.py` as specified in Django docs and add an empty `__init__.py` file to each folder then Django test will auto detect and add the tests to test suite, which is more pragmatic than what I was doing in the post when I asked.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-unit-testing-to-your-django-project
https://realpython.com/testing-in-django-part-1-best-practices-and-examples/